# Monaca IDE - console.log never appears

Tags: ide, monaca

X-Post from here, for exposure:  https://community.onsen.io/topic/222/monaca-ide-console-log-never-appears

Odd question, but only once while using Monaca IDE has anything ever shown up in the console.log portion of the IDE itself. It only occurred when I had a device synced via the debugger. I have since tried syncing it and I never get the device to show in the drop down box, it usually says unknown device /www/html/…

Now, do know that I have put several console.log(‘test’); lines of code to try this out and still no success. I would think that the IDE’s console area would show the log operations from the emulator and not from the device debugger as it has its own log that is view-able on the device, but this apparently isn’t the case. Is this correct or am I just really missing something simple here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this isn’t that big of an issue, but I figured out the problem. Basically, I keep the Monaca IDE tab open in Chrome all the time (I work via my laptop remotely). When I come back after a long absence (several hours, I don’t know what the time out is), the bottom section in the console has the Chrome error showing, like that page timed out. The IDE is still there, just that section is grayed out.

So to fix this, I would just refresh the page. The section pops back and all is good EXCEPT I just figured out that it is at that moment when the device connection no longer works. I can still click Run on Device and it works - syncing with the device - but the console.log no longer shows up. In order to get that back and working, you have to close the tab and reopen it; then everything works.